# How to calculate cumulative sums of cumulative products using BigQuery&

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with 2 columns `x` and `y`. I need to calculate specific sum for each rows.
The formula for 4 rows looks like this:
[image]

I know how to find cumulative product using `EXP(SUM(LN(y)) OVER (ORDER BY x)`. I have an idea to use `PIVOT` but it seems impossible because it may calculated by more than 100 rows.

Any suggestions  how to make it better??

Comment: please attach sample data and expected output.

Comment: it should works for any non-zero values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it may calculated by more than 100 rows.

Consider below approach - should work for reasonable number of rows

```
with temp as (
  select *, row_number() over(order by x) i
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
select x, y,  
  x * (
    ifnull(sum((select exp(sum(ln(z))) from t.z1 z where not z is null)), 0) +
    ifnull(sum((select 1 / exp(sum(ln(z))) from t.z2 z where not z is null)), 0)
  ) s
from (
  select t1.x, t1.y, t1.i,
    array_agg(if(t1.i < t2.i, null, t2.y)) over(partition by t1.x order by t2.i desc) z1,
    array_agg(if(t1.i < t2.i, t2.y, null)) over(partition by t1.x order by t2.i) z2
  from temp t1, temp t2
) t
group by x, y, i
```

If applied to below dummy data

[image]

output is

[image]